# how to upload image to mongodb using node js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a web app that allows users to upload and search for a recipe. A user can upload a recipe by filling a form and press a button to perform a POST request. I managed to save the recipe object, but I can't assign an image to it. I tried to use Multer, but I get `"underfined"` when I do `log(req.file)`. I followed YouTube tutorials which only had `app.js` and `index.ejs` and it works, so I don't know if it's my Ajax code causing the issue??!!.

I have `main.handlebars` and `main.css`, and I have a folder called uploads but still always get undefined in the terminal, below is part of my code: 
THANKS!!

upload.handlebars:

```
      <label for="Userphrase">Recipe Name:</label>
  <input type = "text" name = "recipeName" id = "recipeName"><br>

  <label>Upload an image:</label>

  <div class="container">
  <input name="myImage" type="file"<br>
</div>
.
.
.
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/public/palindrome.js"></script>
```

Ajax, only the request is here since i do error checking before that:

```
      $("form").submit(function(e){
      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/upload",
    data: obj,
    success: function(data){
      alert("recipe added successfully!");
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
   }
```

index.js:
at the top i have:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: './public/uploads/',
filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
});

const upload = multer ({
storage: storage
}).single('myImage');
```

then inside the POST route i have:

```
router.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
 upload(req, res, (err) => {
if(err){
    res.render('index',{
        msg: err
    });
}else{
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send('test');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send image in form data like

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('imageName', imageFile);
```

on node side user same name('imageName') for multer it will get image from it
for more to multer check 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: sounds silly, but does this go in index.js or in the Ajax code? THANKS

Comment: for form data it will go to ajext and for node you can refer multer link

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, just use HTML form with `enctype` set to `multipart/form-data` on the client side. On the server side, say you're using Node.js, the uploaded files can be found in the `request` provided you're using the `multer` middleware to parse the form data. That's it.

Comment: if i do req.body i see the object I'm posting, but how do I acceess the file being also sent in the request? THANKS

Comment: What do you mean accessing the file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append that file to formData and then send it to server

**Javascript:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#fileUpload')[0].files, function (i, file) {
            formData.append('file', file);
        });

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: //To your route eg: /saveImage,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status != 0) {
                    console.log(result.message)
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result.message)
            }
        });
```

Now at your route use `multer`

**Node**

```
var multer = require('multer')
var path = require("path");

// Check for extension of image
const getExtension = file =>{
    if (file.mimetype == "image/jpeg")
        ext =  ".jpeg"
    else
        ext =".png"
    return ext;
}

//initialize multer
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ 
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '../public/images'))
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + getExtension(file))
    }
 })
 var upload = multer({storage:storage})

router.post('/saveImage', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next)=>{
    if (req.file && req.file.mimetype != 'image/jpeg' && req.file.mimetype != 'image/png') 
        return res.json({
            status:1,
            message:"Please Choose JPG or PNG images"
        })
if(req.file){
            let iamge = "/images/" + req.file.filename
res.json({
            status:0,
            message:"Successfully saved",
            path : image
        })
        }
})
```